# Error: When running command to list all downloadable cask apps

Tags: terminal, homebrew, homebrew-cask

Cask used to run fine but now I'm faced with error when I try:
`brew search --casks`

I get the following error:
*Error: Invalid usage: This command requires at least 1 text or regex argument.*

I may have deleted a file which was in my home directory which looked out of place and may have been some file cask needed. Could this have been the problem?

I tried reinstalling casks but it didn't solve the issue. Brew doctor commands didn't return any problem

Comment: If it requires a regex argument, try `brew search --casks  '.*'`.